# What can I do to stop my female cat from ripping my plant's foilage?

Tags: cats

I love my plants and I don't want to get rid of them. I've had 10 house plants in my home and now I'm down to 6. My female cat is ruining my plants! What can I do to stop her from ripping/chewing up the foilage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're cat is ripping into you plants to get some kind of personal satisfaction. I'll assume she doesn't have access to the outdoors. My cat goes in and out as he pleases and claws up the outside trees and occasionally chews grass, but I have plants all over and he's never shown and interest in them.

I'd do a couple of things. I'd not only try to deter her from the ones she doesn't need to mess with, but offer her alternatives. I would think the deterrent would be fairly simple. Just sprinkle some pepper on top of the potting soil or find something safe that she doesn't like the taste of. I haven't had to stop a cat from chewing on something, but I know they make all kinds of sprays. You could probably find something homemade, you just have to make sure that none of it will harm the cat or the plant.

Another alternative to deter her is a motion sensor mounted on a can of compressed air. You'll find one model here:

[SSCAT](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000RIA95G)

Basically, the cat walks in front of it, trips the motion sensor, and it sends out a burst of air. People use them to keep the cats off of counter tops and the like. The trick with these is to position them so that they don't go off unless someone gets really close to the plant. Also, don't startle and hurt yourself when you go to water them. I haven't looked into them too hard, but I'm sure they have ones where you can use the basic office supply cans to refuel.

Next is a good alternative. Your cat obviously has needs that need to be fulfilled. You need to make sure they're taken care of. Find toys that simulate what she's doing to the plants. Maybe even get tray or tub of some sort and grow her an indoor patch of grass. Barring that, a pot that's just hers that grows catnip or cat grass would be great. She can tear it up to her hearts desire.

If you have the ability in your living situation, you could take her on leashed walks or get her an outdoor enclosure. They range from the simple:

[Simple Enclosure](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002ZAG52)

To the complex:

[Complex Enclosure (let me know if link doesn't work, couldn't test at work)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_iKevNkhXo8)

I don't like the first as there isn't room to get away from ants and it's up to you to move it into the shade if the sun moves. Either way, it gets her outside and helps satisfy her urges.

Answer (score 0):

Put the plant out of reach. Hanging pot may work, if there isn't furniture nearby that can be used as a launch point.

Or put it on a surface she knows and mostly accepts she's not allowed on.

Getting her a plant she *is* allowed to munch on -- a pot of oat grass or something similar -- may or may not help.